# what is the difference between int16 and in32 dtype

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

Required: numpy

```
b = np.arange(10, dtype = 'int16')
print(b)  #prints [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
a = b.view(dtype = 'int32')
print(a) #prints [ 65536 196610 327684 458758 589832] #notice also the space before the first element
```

Can somebody explain what is happenin
g in converting the dtype to 'int32'. I always thought the 'int16' to 'int32' means allocated number of bits will change that is it but clearly i dont understand it

Comment: why is this question rated -1?

Comment: Probably because this question shows little research effort, and is poorly phrased

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the number of bits used to represent each integer, as you say, but consider what happens when you try to print the 10 `int16` words as `int32` words. Each `int32` word will be built from two `int16` words. Thus there will be only 5 `int32`words as you see.

Further, the byte order in 32 bit integers is so that the first 16 bit word will be the LSB bits. Thus looking at the hex representation of your two first words. In 16 bits they are: `0x0000 = 0` and `0x0001 = 1`. When the same bits are used in a 32 bit word, you get `0x0001 0000 = 65536` due to this somewhat unintuitive bit order.

I hope this helps your understanding of the concepts.

Comment: And as far as the space in front of the first element of array `a`; this has something to do with numpys way of representing arrays. It doesn't matter if you create your array as you do above, or in an ordinary fashion as `a = np.array([65536, 196610, 327684, 458758, 589832])`.

Comment: Thank you. why the space though? I dont understand what could possibly be the purpose of creating a dtype change flow like this though. One would assume shifting each by 16bits and padding with 0s

Answer (score 3):

Ref: [Array types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) in Numpy and as per the ndarray.view [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html)

> a.view(dtype=some_dtype) constructs a view of the array’s memory with a different data-type. This can cause a reinterpretation of the bytes of memory.

1. Consider `b = np.arange(10, dtype = 'int16')` 
   It generates an evenly spaced array from 0 to 9. `[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]` 
   1.1 Viewing this array as `int32` merges the array by `(32/16) = 2`.
   Also, trying to do this operation on an odd length array will result in error. 
   The output is `[ 65536 196610 327684 458758 589832]`
   Explanation: `[ 65536 * 1 + 0, 65536 * 3 + 2, 65536 * 5 + 4, 65536 * 7 + 6, 65536 * 9 + 8]`
2. Consider `b = np.arange(10, dtype = 'int32')`
   It is equalivalent to `np.arange(10)` which simply creates an evenly spaced array from 0 to 9. 
   2.1 Viewing this data as `int16` splits each element in the data into `(32/16) = 2` parts.
   Therefore, `a = b.view(dtype = 'int16')` is `[0 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0 8 0 9 0]`
   2.2 Viewing this data as `int8` splits each element in the data into `(32/8) = 4` parts.
   Therefore, `a = b.view(dtype = 'int8')` is `[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 9 0 0 0]`

Comment: thank you very much. one correction maybe.. in 2.2 32/8 = 4 parts you meant?

Comment: @Nitin, I hope my answer solved your problem. Remember you can always accept the answer you found helpful.

Comment: thank you for your lucid and to the point answer but JohanL had already nicely addressed my every issue in his answer before you. so i am accepting his answer

Comment: Yes, you must accept that answer which solved your concern irrespective of the time they post their answer. Good answers might take some additional research time and so fast post shouldn't be the criteria for acceptance:)

Comment: understood. im new to stackoverflow and will keep this in mind